# MYSQL - "#1111 - Invalid use of group function" error

Tags: mysql

I'm programming a weather station for a school project.

In mysql I have 1 table with my readings and another one with calculated values. I wrote a mysql query to update the second table with the calculated values. When I run this query, I receive this error

> 1111 - Invalid use of group function

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

My query:

```
 UPDATE Waarnemingen2 As t1
 INNER JOIN (SELECT `Datum_Tijd`,`Temperatuur`,`Luchtvochtigheid`,`Luchtdruk`,`Regenhoeveelheid` FROM Waarnemingen GROUP BY day(`Datum_Tijd`) + hour(`Datum_Tijd`)) as t2 
 SET t1.`Min. temperatuur` = MIN(`Temperatuur`), 
     t1.`Gem. temperatuur` = AVG(`Temperatuur`), 
     t1.`Max. temperatuur` = MAX(`Temperatuur`), 
     t1.`Min. luchtvochtigheid` = MIN(`Luchtvochtigheid`), 
     t1.`Gem. luchtvochtigheid` = AVG(`Luchtvochtigheid`), 
     t1.`Max. luchtvochtigheid` = MAX(`Luchtvochtigheid`), 
     t1.`Min. luchtdruk` = MIN(`Luchtdruk`), 
     t1.`Gem. luchtdruk` = AVG(`Luchtdruk`), 
     t1.`Max. luchtdruk` = MAX(`Luchtdruk`), 
     t1.`Regen` = SUM(`Regenhoeveelheid`)
```

The query should take the minimum, maximum and average from the columns "Temperatuur", "Luchtvochtigheid" and "Luchtdruk" from each hour.

Is there someone who can help me?

Comment: No need of `GROUP BY day(`Datum_Tijd`) + hour(`Datum_Tijd`)` if you are not using any AGGREGATE function

Comment: @JayDipJ GROUP by without an aggregate creates distincts, so not entirely useless.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is because you have unaggregated columns in a SELECT statement that are not in your GROUP by clause.

In a SELECT with a GROUP BY, the only columns you can select are:

- aggregations (MAX(Temperatur), MIN(Luchtdruk), etc.)
- grouped columns

Otherwise you get this error.

Change your subquery to perform your aggregations and then just assign those aggregated values to your joined table.

(I don't know MySQL syntax, this code won't work in SQL Server because it does UPDATE JOINs a little differently, but the important concept is the aggregation.)

i.e.

```
UPDATE Waarnemingen2 As t1
 INNER JOIN (

SELECT day(`Datum_Tijd`) as day, hour(`Datum_Tijd`) as hour, MIN(Temperatur) as Min_Temperature FROM Waarnemingen GROUP BY day(`Datum_Tijd`) , hour(`Datum_Tijd`)
) t2 on t1.day = t2.day and t1.hour = t2.hour
set
t1.MinTemp =  t2.Mintemp
```